# how to rewrite htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How rewrite using htacess.

I have table "category" and the values bellow.

```
id   name    status
1    php     A
2    java    A
3    ruby    A
4    perl    A
```

```
www.sample.com/category.php?id=1
www.sample.com/category.php?id=2
www.sample.com/category.php?id=3
www.sample.com/category.php?id=4
```

I want to change the above url to:

```
www.sample.com/php/1  
www.sample.com/java/2  
www.sample.com/ruby/3  
www.sample.com/perl/4
```

Help guys my problem

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category\.php\?id=1$ php/1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category\.php\?id=2$ java/2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category\.php\?id=3$ ruby/3 [L]
RewriteRule ^category\.php\?id=4$ perl/4 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(php|java|ruby|perl)/([0-9]+)/?$  /category.php?id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```